# MySQL вывод значений

Tags: mysql, select

Как вывести данные, где `col1 < col2`

```
ID COL1 COL2
-----------
10 4  8
11 3  3
12 4  4
13 5  12
```

На примере должно вывести значения строк, где `id` равно 10 и 13

Comment: Не стыдно? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 < col2`

Comment: Мне очень стыдно..)

Comment: Очевидно же как

Comment: да, но в PDO не работает... вот код:

if(array_find('sm',  $link_cat)==true) { $sm=" AND col1 < :col1"; } else { $sm=''; }

if($sm!='') { $stmt_search_res->bindValue(':col1', col2, PDO::PARAM_INT); }

Comment: Не надо постить код в каменты - надо править свой вопрос, добавляя в него существенные данные. И вопрос-то, получается, не по MySQL, а по PHP...

Comment: И - в качестве параметра можно передавать значение (литерал), но уж никак не имя поля.